# How can I convert BGL to MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, database, dictionary, converters

How can i convert Babylon glossaries (*.BGL) to a database table (mySQL) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there are any "easy" ways per say to do it, but two ways come to mind depending on what resources you have.

Export the BGL data directly to a CSV and then set up your database structure within MySQL and import the CSV.

Or

Export the BGL data to MS Excel and then from there you there are multiple formats that you can export to that are importable by MySQL.

There are also several paid solutions that are out there that you can purchase to make the transition a little easier, but I don't know of any that are free, and I can't speak to the quality of any of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eli, I am fine with using CSV and MS Excel sheets but that problem is how i can convert BGL to CSV or Excel Sheet ?

Comment: Depending on your resources at hand, this should be doable from Ubuntu Linux: `dictconv test.BGL -o test.csv` [http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread96152.html](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread96152.html) - Just mudify it to export to .csv instead.

Or Windows 2000 and XP might be able to do it like so from command line:
`relog test.blg -f CSV -o test.csv`

Comment: I am on windows and currnetly dosn't have any access to linux :(       and relog can only convert from bLG not bGL :|

Comment: My mistake I misread relog's manual. I don't really see any other Windows utilities.  Could you download a Ubuntu iso and burn a live boot CD that you could use for this purpose?  If not, I have several Ubuntu system, I could always try making the conversion for you.

I will keep looking for any Windows based solutions.

Comment: Actually, I just played around with `dictconv` on one of my Ubuntu systems and it would appear they don't support CSV like they used to.  However, you can export to .dic which is plain text and from there you should be able to easily either in Excel, or by PHP, or possibly even by a program that already exists be able to convert the .dic to a .csv.

Keep in mind that your .dic is going to be about double the size of your .bgl as you are converting from compiled to plain text.

Comment: I just successfully converted a **.BGL** in UBUNTU to a **.DIC** with `dictconv` and then I imported the .DIC as **tab delimited** in Excel and saved/exported as **.CSV**.  Everything worked well and the final file looks correct.

Not the prettiest solution, but at least it works.

Comment: Awesome then, i am going to install ubuntu and give it a try ! thanks alot ELi !

Answer (score 5):

You can use PyGlossary

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyglossary/

Tested and working.

Description of PyGlossay:

Working on glossarys (dictionary databases) using python. Including editing glossarys and converting theme between many formats such as: Tabfile StarDict format xFarDic format "Babylon Builder" source format Omnidic format and etc.